# LabelBinarizer yields different result in multiclass example

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, one-hot-encoding

When executing the multiclass example in the scikit-learn tutorial

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#multiclass-vs-multilabel-fitting

I came across a slight oddity.

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
0.19.1

>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

>>> X = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [4, 5], [3, 2], [3, 1]]
>>> y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2] # Three classes

>>> clf = OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=SVC(random_state=0))
>>> clf.fit(X, y).predict(X)
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2])
```

This is all fine. Now with one-hot encoding:

```
>>> y = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)
>>> y
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

I would expect the label *binarizer* to only *encode* the target, but not having an influence on the classifier. However it yields a different result:

```
>>> clf.fit(X, y).predict(X)
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Notebook on Google Colab (where the same code yields yet a different error, strangely):

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/13dZ2aVbKTMgPOxj2SLsas2U2mOoKng2M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OneVsRestClassifier` is applying  `LabelBinarizer` itself under the hood (the source code in [`sklearn/multiclass.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/multiclass.py#L183)):

```
def fit(self, X, y):
  ...
  self.label_binarizer_ = LabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)
  Y = self.label_binarizer_.fit_transform(y)
  Y = Y.tocsc()
  self.classes_ = self.label_binarizer_.classes_
```

So extra manual conversion is unnecessary. In fact, it's interpreting your one-hot encoded `y` as *multi-label* input. From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.fit):

> `y` : (sparse) array-like, `shape = [n_samples, ], [n_samples, n_classes]`
>
> Multi-class targets. An indicator matrix turns on multilabel
>   classification.